# dynamic way to post form input

Tags: php, html

Is there a way to post form input dynamically.

For example instead of

`$name = $_POST['name']` e.t.c

you have something like

for each form input `POST` to database. I need a dynamic way so that if my form changes I don't have to change my `POSTing` script as well.

Comment: `$_POST` is an array so you can run foreach on it. However you'll end up wanting to have a validation (eg. to check that only the fields you want get submitted) and sanitization of submitted values. Anyway you could make some mechanism of your own or use a solution already created and provided by some [framework](http://doc.nette.org/en/2.3/forms)

Comment: @saina the $_POST idea  works perfectly but the array includes the button value I guess that's where the validation comes in. could I also use DomDocuments to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your `$_REQUEST` data at server side using `foreach()` function like:

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $req)
{
  //all your form data will be available here
}
```

**Note:** I used `$_REQUEST` here but you can use $_GET or $_POST as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You could have some fixed fields that you will always have (name / username / e-mail address / etc.) and store these in a fixed table.

Then you get the ID of that row and you store the rest of the fields as key - value pairs in another table where the key is the name of the `input` and the value its value. In that table you also add the post ID so that you know which post the pair belongs to. If needed, you could add some additional fields with properties like what kind of field it is, the order, etc..